# VM cannot autostart due to insufficient resources?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, esxi

Using ESXI 7.0 update 2.

I have an autostart configured for a VM.  I tried testing it by turning the ESXI off/on via my IDRAC interface, and I am now seeing this error when it tries to turn the VM on during autostart -

[image]

`Result- Insufficent Resources`

The start delay was 120 seconds, I tried changing it to 240 but am still seeing this.  1) is there a way to get more details on the result message?  2) How can I resolve this?  Longer delay start time?  Something else?

Edit 1: We are using a Dell PowerEdge T440.  Intel Xeon Silver 4214 CPU @2.20 GHZ Core Count 12.  64 Gigs of ram.  I can give additional details if you tell me what you want to know.  The VM (there is only one set to autostart) has 4 cores and 16 gigs of ram allocated.

Comment: Can it be run manually, not autostart? What hardware do you use? Insufficient info to help.

Comment: Yes I can run it manually.  That is part 1 of my question - how do I get more information from this result/from ESXI about what resources specifically/what error code exactly?

Comment: I know when you start a VM normal, logs are started by ESXi (vSphere), have you checked the contents of any logs created during the time where the VM should have automatically started.